# flutter -- What is the object creation order when creating a mobile app?

Tags: flutter, dart

Suppose the main.dart file for an app includes this code:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      //theme, etc.,
      home: StoryPage(),
    );
  }
}

SomeCustomClass myCustomClass = SomeCustomClass();

class StoryPage extends StatefulWidget {
  _StoryPageState createState() => _StoryPageState();
}

class _StoryPageState extends State<StoryPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //more code ...
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out the order objects are created in. I assume

1. `main()` is run first, which
2. creates the StatelessWidget `MyApp` object forming the basis for the app. As `MyApp` is built, it
3. creates a StatefulWidget `StoryPage` object.

Is all that accurate? And, if so, when is `myCustomClass` instantiated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`main()` is always the first function to be invoked. it's called before any other Dart code in your application.

All top level and static objects are created *lazily* the first time they are accessed. To demonstrate, try running the following code:

```
final Foo foo = Foo();

void main() {
  print('hello');
  foo.toString(); // Just to access foo.
}

class Foo {
  Foo() { print('world'); }
}
```

If top level objects were constructed before main, then you would see 'world\nhello'. Instead we correctly see `hello\nworld`.

Any `const` objects are created "at compile time" so there is no object creation done at runtime. They exist as data in the program's memory. This can't be observed of course, as construction of a const object cannot have side effects by design.